# Валидатор для build.xml ANT

Tags: валидация, xmlparser, ant, build-automation

В задании требуется создать валидатор с помощью StAX для проверки сценария сборки проекта на Apache Ant. 
подскажите какой-нибудь пример создания валидатора для проекта. Как он должен выглядеть и что должен проверять? ничего не могу прогуглить по этой теме.
вот мой build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="my_test_project" default="execute">
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <target name="hello-world">
        <echo>Hello, I Ant and I working!</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="make.dirs" description="Make some dirs" depends="hello-world, clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.class.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.path}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="make.dirs" description="compile the source ">
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src.dir} into ${build.dir} -->
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.path}" destdir="${build.class.dir}">
            <!-- <src path="${src.path}" /> -->

        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="archive" depends="compile" description="Creates the JAR file">
        <jar destfile="dist/project.jar" basedir="${build.class.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="execute" depends="compile, archive" description="Runs the program">
        <echo level="warning" message="running" />
        <java classname="Main.Runner" classpath="${build.class.dir}">

        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="clean up">
        <echo>Cleaning up...</echo>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.path}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот нашел такой валидатор:

```
<!--Declaration of the buildfilevalidator -->
<taskdef name="buildfilevalidator" classname="MyTask">
    <classpath>
        <path location="validator"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>


<target name="validate-buildfile">
    <!--
        checkdepends - if targets with depends are used instead of "main" point
        checkdefaults - if project contains default attribute
        checknames - if names contains only letters with '-'
        ...
        etc.
    -->
    <buildfilevalidator checkdepends="true" checkdefault="true" checknames="true">
        <buildfile location="..\build.xml"/>
        <!-- <buildfile location="A path to another buildfile" /> -->
    </buildfilevalidator>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="validate-buildfile">
</target>
```

но описания к нему нет. найти как работают задачи taskdef например тоже ничего путного найти не могу, помогите пожалуйста.

По taskdef вот что только: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html ,
а атрибут classname что там делает, что он выполняет. Ведь имя "buildfilevalidator" указано, а это тогда что?
 это путь, но про location ничего опять найти не могу. Чему она должна быть равна?

Я так понимаю там должен указываться путь, но ни сокращенный (от места расположения build.xml), ни полный ничего не дает выбрасывает следующую  ошибку

C:\Users\Pavel_Butkevich\workspace\Collections_LFU_LRU Sinhr\build-validator.xml:6: taskdef class MyTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]